# GMail plugin injection

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, gmail

I'm actually developing a GMail extensions for chrome. Everything is working fine except my plugin injection.
I am triggering the hashchange event and checking if i have to inject my plugin for this context.

Example : If i get something that match with "#inbox/xxxxxxx" i'll inject my plugin but if i get something like this : "#inbox/p2" i will not inject it because it's the listing context.

It's working fine when the user isn't spamming the next/previous mail button, or spamming some hashchange (When you click on "compose new message" the hash change but i don't want to reload my plugin)

I'm using the regexp to catch which context is ok for the injection :

```
if((/^#(inbox)\/(.*)\b/.test(location.hash)) || (/^#(drafts)\/(.*)\b/.test(location.hash)) || (/^#(search)((\/([^\/])+){2})/.test(location.hash)) || (/^#(imp)\/(.*)/.test(location.hash)) || (/^#(label)((\/([^\/])+){2})/.test(location.hash)) || (/^#(all)\/(.*)/.test(location.hash)) || (/^#(spam)\/(.*)/.test(location.hash)) || (/^#(category)\/(.*)/.test(location.hash)) || (/^#(trash)\/(.*)/.test(location.hash))){

  if((/(compose=)(.*)$/.test(location.hash)) || (/(projector=1)$/.test(location.hash)) || (/^#(inbox)\/p(.*)\b/.test(location.hash)) || (/^#(drafts)\/p(.*)\b/.test(location.hash)) || (/^#(search)\/p(.*)\/(.*)/.test(location.hash)) || (/^#(imp)\/p(.*)/.test(location.hash)) || (/^#(label)\/p(.*)\/(.*)/.test(location.hash)) || (/^#(all)\/p(.*)/.test(location.hash)) || (/^#(spam)\/p(.*)\/(.*)/.test(location.hash)) || (/^#(category)\/p(.*)\/(.*)/.test(location.hash)) || (/^#(trash)\/p(.*)/.test(location.hash))) {
      console.log("Stop the script");
      return;
  }

  //the construction of my plugin
```

}

The problem is that when the user go to the mail overview and compose a new message, the hash go from "#inbox/xxxxxxxxx" to "#inbox/xxxxxxxxx?compose=new" so i set the `/(compose=)(.*)$/` but if the user close the mail window, the hash is again : "#inbox/xxxxxxxxx" and the plugin is loading again.

I don't know if this hash solution is the best since i get some problem like this. I would like to get some advices or solution to inject my plugin only when i'm on one mail overview.
(My plugin is really close to rapportive)
Hope all of this is clear enough.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You could toggle the visibility of the plugin instead of unloading / reloading it when the compose mole is opened / closed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do not want to change the visibility of my plugin when the user open a "compose mail" but the problem is that i can kick the hash when he open the compose mail (hash : "#inbox/xxxxx?compose=new") but not when he close it and the hash go back to "#inbox/xxxxx" which is a good one. (the same when the user is on a mail overview)